# Networkx: get numbers of edges, that are in clusters

Tags: python, networkx

I have the graph
[![network][1]][1]
I try to get the number  of edges in clusters in `networkx`, but I don't find a function to do this.  How should I calculate the number of edges in clusters in the graph?

Comment: Can we guess your code? *If so, we'd sell your code.*

Comment: Fix grammar and usage so the question is more clear to native English speakers.  I thought this question was too unclear even with the edit, but given the answer, apparently it is enough to get a high quality answer.  Also, focused on asking how to find the edges rather than on finding a tool to be more in line with stackoverflow conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Cluster in networks are so-called subgraphs in `networkx`. In order to obtain subgraphs in a graph or network, you can use the `networkx.connected_components` or `networkx.connected_component_subgraphs` functions. The first one returns lists with nodes while the latter one actually returns subgraphs.

**Note**: These functions return generators, so you need to convert them to lists in order to obtain the graphs.

An example might look like this:

```
import networkx as nx
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from(((1, 2), (2,3), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7)))
subgraphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph))
for subgraph in subgraphs:
    edges = subgraph.edges()
    print(edges, "total edges: %s" % len(edges))

[[1, 2], [2, 3]] total edges: 2
[[4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]], total edges: 3
```

Comment: There some clusters at the graph. I need to get numbers of edges, that are included in graph

Comment: Do you mean, that you have isolated subgraphs in your network?

Comment: yes. And I need to get number of edges in this subgraph

Comment: I edited my answer, I am sorry that I misunderstood initially.

Comment: That's strange, but for graphs, there are obviously 2 cluster, it returns me 1 cluster

Comment: Are you 100 % sure that you have 2 subgraphs? How do you generate the graph?

Comment: Can you say, is any way to generate network wth 2 clusters to check that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145140/discussion-between-christoph-engwer-and-petr-petrov).